# Angular2 @Input() Array not being set

Tags: angular, angular2-template, typescript2.0

Trying to pass an array to a @Input() parameters but it's not displaying at all.

```
<ng-container *ngIf = "searchResults != undefined">
   <searchresult *ngFor = "let result of searchResults;" 
      [title] = 'result.title'
      [authorName] = 'result.authorName'
      [content] = 'result.content'
      [tagList] = "result.tagList"
   ></searchresult>
</ng-container>

<p *ngIf = "searchResults == undefined">loading...</p>
```

and then in searchresult I have

```
<div class = "search-result">

<div class = 'result-top-section'>
    <div class = 'author-profile'>
         <img width = '70' height = '70' class = 'profile-icon' src= '/images/ogpfp.png'/>
         <p>{{ authorName }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class = 'content'>
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = 'result-tag-row'>
        <tag *ngFor = "let tag of tagList;" [tagName] = 'tag'></tag>
</div>
```

this is the SearchResultComponent class

```
@Component({
 selector: 'searchresult',
 templateUrl: './searchResult.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./searchResult.component.css']
})

export class SearchResultComponent implements ISearchResult{

 @Input()
 title: string;

 @Input()
 authorName: string;

 @Input()
 content: string;

 @Input()
 tagList: string[];
}
```

https://snag.gy/Nt4JIo.jpg
this is the array, so as you can see the tag list is populated

https://snag.gy/SIX0Gs.jpg
this is what the html outputs, as you can see every input property is set except for the tag list

I'm probably missing something here, if there's anything let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `[tagList] = "result.tagList"` to `[tagList] = "result.tags"`.

Comment: @cyr-x my guy, you just saved me a lot of trouble. For that, I thank you, god bless. Post your answer and I will more than gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you made a typo (`result.tagList` instead of `result.tags`) when binding the tags list to the `tagsList` input of your `searchresult` component.

To fix the problem you have to change the binding to `[tagList] = "result.tags"`.